# PyQt: QProgressDialog shows but is empty (displays background content)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a piece of code that I have used elsewhere (where it does exactly what I want), but in this case it does not. Basically my function body calculates a bunch of things, lumps the results into a pandas DataFrame and plots this to a matplotlib canvas.

I put the code below at the top of my function body, hoping for it to display a dialog box for the duration of the function call. However, all that happens is the dialog box appears, with the box contents reflecting what is immediately behind it on screen. This remains on the screen for the duration of the function call and then correctly closes when it has finished running.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

In case it's useful, the parent (`self`), is a `QWidget`.

Oh and one more thing, if I remove the `progress.cancel()` line, once the main part of the function has finished executing, the `QProgressDialog` actually paints itself with the progress bar and label text ('Updating...').

Thanks very much for your help!

```
progress = QProgressDialog( parent = self )
progress.setCancelButton( None )
progress.setLabelText( 'Updating...' )
progress.setMinimum( 0 )
progress.setMaximum( 0 )
progress.forceShow()

#calculate and plot DataFrame

progress.cancel()
```

Comment: You could try app.processEvents(), where app is the QApplication instance, before entering the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there an easy way I can access the application instance from inside my class?

Comment: `QtGui.QApplication.instance()`

Comment: @mdurant that has partially solved the problem! The box now correctly paints itself, but the bar does not animate until the calculation finishes, at which point the dialog disappears (`progress.cancel()` present) or animates the progress bar (`progress.cancel()` not present). Any ideas?

Comment: The bar will only update when idle, from the event-loop. If you want to animate while doing a big calculation, you'll have to do processEvents() (or a manual draw) each time you update it. Often in such situations, the calculation is explicitly put in a separate thread.

Comment: I think we've encountered some gaps in my knowledge here. Anyway, what confuses me is that I've implemented something similar before, and in that case the dialog correctly animates while something else is working. What could the difference be here? How does the unfixed `QProgressBar` (i.e. `progress.setMaximum( 0 )`) ever work without using processEvents()? Really appreciate your time and effort - apologies for all the follow-up questions!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing it, sorry.

Comment: OK, old thread, but I've been banging my head against a brick wall all morning with a very similar problem, and app.processEvents() finally solved it. Thank you so much mdurant, if you're still here :)

Answer (score 0):

I found myself having the same problem at some point and came up with this decorator that I apply to functions that I want to run blocking, while permitting GUI thread to process events.

```
def nongui(fun):
    """Decorator running the function in non-gui thread while
    processing the gui events."""
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
        async = pool.apply_async(fun, args, kwargs)
        while not async.ready():
            async.wait(0.01)
            QApplication.processEvents()
        return async.get()

    return wrap
```

Then, it's easy to write your calculating function normally with the decorator:

```
@nongui
def work(input):
    # Here you calculate the output and set the 
    # progress dialog value
    return out
```

and then run it as usual:

```
out = work(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
progress = QProgressDialog( parent = self )
progress.setCancelButton( None )
progress.setLabelText( 'Updating...' )
progress.setMinimum( 0 )
progress.setMaximum( 10 )
progress.forceShow()

progress.setValue(0)

#calculate and plot DataFrame
domystuff(progress) # pass progress to your function so you can continue to increment progress

qApp.processEvents() # qApp is a reference to QApplication instance, available within QtGui module. Can use this whereever you are in your code, including lines in your domystuff() function.


progress.setValue(10) # progress bar moves to 100% (based on our maximum of 10 above)



progress.done() # I don't think you want to cancel. This is inherited from QDialog
```

Comment: After a bit more reading, whenever setValue() is called, processEvents() is also called.  When setValue(max) is called, the dialogue is complete and exits. progress.done() isn't actually needed.